# How can I jump to a point slightly above the fragment identifier?

Tags: html, fragment-identifier

I don't like how the fragment identifier jumps to the actual point of where the content begins on the page. It looks awkward having the box start right at the top of the screen. It kind of bugs me. So I was using an anchor with a name attribute above it, set to `display: block` so that it would pay attention to the 10px margin on the top of the box below it. Using this method, it essentially jumped down to that content, with 10px spacing between the start of the content and the actual top edge of the browser window.

```
<a name="some-text"></a>
```

But it seems that I'm no longer allowed to do this in HTML5, as when I try to validate the page, I get this nice warning:

> The name attribute is obsolete. Consider putting an id attribute on the nearest container instead.

I can't just change all the `name` attributes to `id` attributes because it becomes an empty hyperlink rather than a named anchor (I've also tried, the `display: block` no longer gets applied to it).

So, given a group of divisions, like so:

```
<div>Content</div>
<div>Content</div>
<div>Content</div>
<div>Content</div>
```

and assuming that they all have a 10px margin applied to the top of them, is there any way to re-apply the IDs to them so that when I use fragment identifiers to jump to different spots, it still includes the 10px space between the content and the top edge of the browser window?

**Note:** I've tried applying the ID directly to each division, but the browser ignores the margin on the element when determining where to jump.

Comment: This gets especially annoying when there are fixed elements at the top getting in the way, which I've had to deal with more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get you right at first, let me try again. You say:

> I can't just change all the name attributes to id attributes because it becomes an empty hyperlink rather than a named anchor (I've also tried, the display: block no longer gets applied to it).

I don't really understand where is the problem here or why would you like it to use `display: block`. Its purpose as I and apparently the W3C see it is a [placeholder](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#placeholder-hyperlink), it should act as an anchor like it did in HTML4, only using `id` instead of the `name` attribute.

If you'll run this simple html through the W3C's markup validator you'll see it is valid html5.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="test"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

So it comes down to these two options:

a. I didn't get something right, I'm sorry and hope you'll be able to correct my mistake.

b. You are going out of your way to accomplish things that could be easily achieved.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're getting at. I don't want to move it up 10px, I want to move it down. Also, moving the element which *has* the ID on it would still cause the browser to jump to the spot where the element is actually located.

Comment: I misunderstood you at first. Hope this time around I'm a bit more helpful. I edited my answer.

Comment: That's interesting. Theoretically it should still work, but browsers don't render it the same with an `id` attribute as they do with a `name` attribute. That's the problem I'm having: rendering. I know it validates fine with an `id`.

Comment: All browsers? Sounds interesting, I'll definitely give it a closer look.

Comment: If a jsFiddle is at all possible I think it would be a great example for your problem.

Comment: Hmmm, I was able to get it to work by moving the anchor down below the HTML comment, so it goes `<!-- --><a id></a><div></div>` and the display appears to be working. Also interesting, IE9 appears to pay attention to the margin so this isn't even necessary. But I don't think HTML comments should be affecting anything like this. It would be nice if all browsers paid attention to the margin... They really should, since the anchor is outside of the margin. -.-

Comment: It would be nice if browsers had consistency, now wouldn't it? Story of the web :)

Answer (score 1):

Use padding could avoid this problem. As margin is not included in the content boundaries, so the browser would ignore it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="1">How can I jump to a point slightly above the fragment identifier?<br/>
up vote 2 down vote favorite</div>

<div id="2">
I don't like how the fragment identifier jumps to the actual point of where the content begins on the page. It looks awkward having the box start right at the top of the screen. It kind of bugs me. So I was using an anchor with a name attribute above it, set to display: block so that it would pay attention to the 10px margin on the top of the box below it. Using this method, it essentially jumped down to that content, with 10px spacing between the start of the content and the actual top edge of the browser window.</div>

<div id="3">
But it seems that I'm no longer allowed to do this in HTML5, as when I try to validate the page, I get this nice warning:</div>

<div id="4">
    The name attribute is obsolete. Consider putting an id attribute on the nearest container instead.</div>

<div id="5">
I can't just change all the name attributes to id attributes because it becomes an empty hyperlink rather than a named anchor (I've also tried, the display: block no longer gets applied to it).</div>

<div id="6">
So, given a group of divisions, like so:</div>

<div id="7">Content</div>
<div id="8">Content</div>
<div id="9">Content</div>
<div id="10">Content</div>

<div id="11">
and assuming that they all have a 10px margin applied to the top of them, is there any way to re-apply the IDs to them so that when I use fragment identifiers to jump to different spots, it still includes the 10px space between the content and the top edge of the browser window?</div>

<div id="12">
Note: I've tried applying the ID directly to each division, but the browser ignores the margin on the element when determining where to jump.</div>

<div id="13">
html fragment-identifier</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: While this would work for a bare, unstyled box, the boxes will likely have borders and padding applied to them in the future, which would cause this not to work anymore. +1 for knowing about padding, though.

Comment: I would recommend you to use scripting solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
.spacer{height:25px;}​
```

Place an element with a class that has the height you want immediately after the anchor.

Fiddle example. http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/sJEkQ/3/